# How to handle database operations using threadpool and entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, threadpool

I really need some code examples here... What I am trying to do:

```
GetCollectionFromDatabase
foreach item
{
    resetEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    var makeRequest = new MakeRequest(resetEvents[i]);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(makeRequest.ThreadPoolCallback), i);
}
db.Save();

ThreadPoolCallback    
{
    update/delete the row 
}
```

Is this the right appoach? Do I pass in the db as a ref to the `ThreadPoolCallBack`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a context within the thread pool callback. Entity framework contexts are not multi threaded and cannot be shared by different threads.

I take it `db` is your database context in this case. You will have to create a new one in `ThreadPoolCallback` and save it there.